# Popup is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

**Code:**

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">
        Reward added to Employee
    </div>


    $("#AddReward").click(function ()
        {
            EmployeeId=JSON.stringify(currentEmployeeId=@Model.EmployeeId)

            GivenOn=JSON.valueOf(givenOn=@Model.GivenOn)

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("AddRewardToEmployee", "Employee"))",
                data: {
                    "employeeId":EmployeeId,

                    "givenOn":GivenOn
                },
                               success: function (data)
                {

                    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        title: "Resource Added",
                        height: 200,
                        width: 300,
                        buttons: {
                            "Ok": function (e)
                            {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                                window.location.href="/Employee/Edit?employeeId="+@Model.EmployeeId;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },


            });

        });
```

**Background:**

Here in AddRewardToEmployee action i'm adding reward to employee and then i want to display the popup to that reward is added successfully.

**Question:**

Action method i.e AddRewardToEmployee is working fine but popup is not getting displayed.Is there anything wrong in script?

Comment: Have you checked console, if there are any errors? What is version of used jquery ui?

Comment: 1.11.2 version of jquery ui.

Comment: I checked the console ,while displaying the AddRewardToEmployee view it is showing...Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).But still it is working but didn't show popup.

Comment: Try to localize error. Comment code related to creating dialog (`$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({ ...` ), and check if you still have an error.

Also use `var` before `EmployeeId` & `GivenOn` and `;` after.

Comment: That error is not b'coz of Popup code,It was b'coz of following line.... GivenOn=JSON.valueOf(givenOn=@Model.GivenOn) 
After removing this line code is still working fine coz givenon is a date and it is nullable.

Comment: What is `JSON.valueOf` method ? I could not find the documentation for that in the internet !